# Plotting points of the form $(-p \mod(n),0)$ and $(p,0)$

Tags: calculus, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, graphing-functions

Imagine taking an interval $[-n,n]$ of the $x$-axis, cutting it in half at $x=0,$ and gluing the sides over top of each other. This process is equivalent to thinking about points of the form:

$(-x \mod(n),0).$

I wanted to restrict the values of $x$ and to consider points of the form: $$(-p\mod(n),0)$$

on the interval $[-n,n],$ where $n\in \Bbb Z$ and $-p$ is a prime greater than $-n.$

Furthermore, I plotted points of the form $(p,0)$ where $p$ is prime on the same plot. So the distribution consists of points of the form $(p,0)$ and also $(-p\mod(n),0).$

Here is the distribution of points of the form $(-p \mod(10),0)$ and $(p,0)$:

[image]

Here is the distribution of points of the form $(-p \mod(200),0)$ and $(p,0):$

[image]

**Questions:**

$1)$ What is the natural density of the distribution of points and does it converge as the interval gets larger?

The [Natural Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) is a way to measure how large a subset of the natural numbers is. The way to calculate it, is to count the number of points and then divide it by the total number of natural numbers in the interval.

I think the natural density on the interval $[0,10],$ is $\frac{5}{11},$ and on the interval $[0,200]$ is $\frac{76}{201}.$ Are these right?

Comment: Show work Please.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @RoddyMacPhee work has been included.

Comment: is this homework ?

Comment: No this is a little question I am thinking about

Comment: 4 actually. but who's counting.

Comment: your plot for 10 is wrong by the way @Ultradark

Comment: Your question is "give a question one might be interested in asking"? So, you don't know any interesting questions about this setup? That would seem to indicate that you don't find anything interesting about your own question. In which case, my question is, why are you asking a question that you don't find interesting yourself? I would suggest you come back when you have an interesting question to ask, even if it's only interesting to yourself.

Comment: I thought of a question @GerryMyerson

Comment: The number of points is no more than twice the number of primes, and the primes have density zero.

Comment: So, does that answer your question, Ultra?

Comment: Yes that answers my question